# explode timestamp range to MINUTES sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

| start | end |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 08:20:06 | 2021-01-01 08:26:05 |

I need to expand that time range to rows:

| timestamp |
| --- |
| 2021-01-01 08:20:06 |
| 2021-01-01 08:21:06 |
| 2021-01-01 08:22:06 |
| 2021-01-01 08:23:06 |
| 2021-01-01 08:24:06 |
| 2021-01-01 08:25:06 |
| 2021-01-01 08:26:05 |

I can do it in python but is there any way in sql server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method uses a recursive CTE;

```
with cte as (
      select start, end
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(minute, 1, start), end
      from cte
      where start < end
     )
select start
from cte
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

A *far* more performant method, than an rCTE, would be a tally. *Assuming* that you could have multiple rows in the source table:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,StartDate,EndDate)) FROM dbo.YourTable)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --up to1,000 rows. Add more cross joins for more rows
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,T.I,YT.StartDate) AS YourDate
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN Tally T ON T.I >= DATEDIFF(MINUTE,YT.StartDate,YT.EndDate);
```